# Создание аудиофайла из сэмплов (аудиофайлов)

Tags: android, java

Есть в наличии 12 сэмплов (ogg файлов, но думаю формат не важен, можно и wav) которые нужно сохранить в виде мелодии (между кусочками одинаковая пауза, до 12 кусочков одновременно играть может). Может есть какая библиотека для этого. Интересует решение для Java.

Comment: О, Господи, опять мне что ли писать?

Comment: Ну если иначе никак, то было бы неплохо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под vanilla Java есть такое решение по конкатенации 2-х аудио файлов:

```
AudioInputStream myClip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(clipFile1));
AudioInputStream myClip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(clipFile2));
AudioInputStream appendedFiles = new AudioInputStream(
                               new SequenceInputStream(myClip1, myClip2),     
                               myClip1.getFormat(), 
                               myClip1.getFrameLength() + myClip2.getFrameLength());
AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                               new File("AppendedClip.wav"));
```

Под Android сейчас не работает - где в районе API 9-10 поддержка пакета **javax.sound.sampled** была убрана по неизвестным причинам

Comment: А какое сейчас подобное решение для Android?

Comment: Да хз... не заморачивался